# Execute oracle function with php having a custom array as a parameter

Tags: php, arrays, oracle, function, parameters

I have an oracle function which has an array as a parameter as below:

```
addGroups($empGroupId, $employees);
```

and it adds groups of employees 
but this array parameter is defined as a custom type in oracle data base as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EMPLOYEES."ARR_VAR2"  is table of varchar2(32000);
```

I tried to call this function in php and pass this array as below:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);

//recieving parameters
$empGroupId= $request->ID;
$employees= $request->EMPLOYEES;

//establish connection
$conn = oci_connect("EMPLOYEES", "****", "ip/orcl");

//test connection
if ($conn)
{
  if($empGroupId!=NULL && $employees!=NULL)
  {
      $stmt =  "begin :resu :=addGroups(:empGroupId,:employees, :result ); end;";
      $stid=oci_parse($conn,$stmt);

      oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":empGroupId", $empGroupId);
      oci_bind_array_by_name($stid, ":employees", $employees, 250, 250, SQLT_VCS );
      oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":result", $result, 40);
      oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":resu", $resu, 100);

      oci_execute($stid);
      oci_free_statement($stid);

      $result1['output'] = array("result" => $result);
      return $result1;
else
{
//connection failed
echo 500;
}
```

but it returns this error:

ORA-01458: invalid length inside variable character string

I also tried oci new collection as below:

```
 $stmt =  "begin :resu :=addGroups(:empGroupId,:employees, :result ); end;";
      $stid=oci_parse($conn,$stmt);

      oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":empGroupId", $empGroupId);
      $IDs= oci_new_collection($conn, 'ARR_VAR', 'EMPLOYEES');
     foreach($employees as $emp)
     {
       $IDs->append($emp);
     }
     oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":employees", $IDs, -1, SQLT_CHR );
      oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":result", $result, 40);
      oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":resu", $resu, 100);

      oci_execute($stid);
      oci_free_statement($stid);

      $result1['output'] = array("result" => $result);
      return $result1;
else
{
//connection failed
echo 500;
}
```

and it gives me this error:

**Warning**:  oci_new_collection():ORA-22318: input type is not an array type

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function append() on boolean

is there any way to solve this

thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't had time to give a real reply.  Look at the PL/SQL chapter in [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html) which should help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much christopher, it was very helpful as my problem was solved and it seemed that i just should have put the pl/sql statement after creating the new collection as below:

```
$conn = $this->conn;
    $IDs = oci_new_collection($conn, 'ARR_VAR');
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($employees ); ++$i)
     {
       $IDs->append($employees[$i]);
     }
    $stmt =  "begin :resu :=addGroups(:empGroupId,:employees, :result ); end;";

    $stid=oci_parse($conn,$stmt);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":empGroupId", $empGroupId);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":employees", $IDs, -1, OCI_B_NTY );
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":result", $result, 40);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":resu", $resu, 100);
    oci_execute($stid);
    oci_free_statement($stid);
    $result1['output'] = array("result" => $result);
    return $result1;
```

Comment: Also look at how [`oci_bind_array_name()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-array-by-name.php) could be used.  There may be performance benefits - even if you have to write some extra PL/SQL wrapper code.